# Printing rhombus in python

Tags: python

I have to print j number of rhombus adjacent to another
That is if i=3 and j=2 then the output should look like

```
  *      *
 * *    * *
* * *  * * *
 * *    * *
  *      *
```

I have wrote a program in python to solve it but iam getting the output one below the other.Can any one help??

```
i,j=map(int,input().split())

def solve(a,b):
    for i in range(a,b):
        print((" "*abs(b))+("* "*abs(i)))
        b-=1
for k in range(0,j):
    solve(0,i),solve(-i,0)
```

Comment: Hint: Explore the documentation on the `print` function. In particular -- learn about the `end` parameter.

Comment: Please be clear with your code. Right now your code doesn't make any sense and has syntax errors. And what is that you are going at ?

Comment: @VineethSai the code works fine

Comment: @Giha It was edited i guess :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you. I tried to keep it as similar to your own code so you can understand.

Let me know if you need any modifications

```
i,j=map(int,input().split())
size = i
def solve(a,b):
    for i in range(a,b):
        spaces =[]
        stars = []
        spaces = list(" " * abs(b))
        stars = list("* " * abs(i))

        final = spaces + stars

        #padding
        while len(final) < ((size*2)-1):
            final.append(" ")

        # popping last space to preserve pattern
        if len(final) == (size * 2):
            final.pop()

        b-=1
        print("".join(final) * j)


for k in range(0,1):
    solve(0,i)
    solve(-i,0)
```

**Output:**

```
5 5

    *        *        *        *        *    
   * *      * *      * *      * *      * *   
  * * *    * * *    * * *    * * *    * * *  
 * * * *  * * * *  * * * *  * * * *  * * * * 
* * * * ** * * * ** * * * ** * * * ** * * * *
 * * * *  * * * *  * * * *  * * * *  * * * * 
  * * *    * * *    * * *    * * *    * * *  
   * *      * *      * *      * *      * *   
    *        *        *        *        *
```

Comment: Thanks sir but why output is overlapping ??

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's easier to duplicate data rather than recreate it. In addition, this gives the proper spacing between rhombuses.

```
i, j = map(int, input().split())

# Create the top half
lines = [];
for lineIndex in range(i):
    lines.append('')

    lines[lineIndex] = ' ' * (i - lineIndex) + '*'
    for idx in range(lineIndex):
        lines[lineIndex] += ' *'
    lines[lineIndex] += ' ' * (i - lineIndex)

# Copy the first lines onto the end in reverse order
for idx in range(i - 2, -1, -1):
    lines.append(lines[idx])

# Create the correct number of rhombuses
for idx in range(len(lines)):
    lines[idx] *= j
    lines[idx] = lines[idx][:-1]

for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

**Output:**

```
4 6
   *        *        *        *        *        *
  * *      * *      * *      * *      * *      * *
 * * *    * * *    * * *    * * *    * * *    * * *
* * * *  * * * *  * * * *  * * * *  * * * *  * * * *
 * * *    * * *    * * *    * * *    * * *    * * *
  * *      * *      * *      * *      * *      * *
   *        *        *        *        *        *
```

If you're looking for a solution a little closer to what you started with, the following should work as well. Note the `end=''` parameter passed into the `print` statement changes the end character printed by `print` from a newline to nothing, allowing you to print all the rhombuses on one line.

```
i,j=map(int,input().split())

def solve(a,b):
    for k in range(a,b):
        print(((' '*abs(b))+('* '*abs(k))+(' '*abs(b))) * j, end='')
        b-=1
        print()
solve(0,i)
solve(-i,0)
```